# ios - ivar is null inside a block, although set before block execution

Tags: ios, block, ivar

I have the following code:

```
[GetUserData getUserDataWithBlock:^(UserData *userData, NSError *error)
              {
                  self.userData = userData;
              #1  self.userData.fbUser = user;
                  // Call REST API of server 'GetAllWords'
                  [GetAllWords getAllWordsWithBlock:^(NSSet *newWords, NSError *error)
                   {
                       [self saveAllWords:newWords];
                   #2  [self showRootView];
                   }];
              }];
```

The problem is, that `self.userData` is correctly set in #1 (and is not null), but when I'm getting to #2 - `self.userData` becomes null...
Point #1 is the only place where I set `self.userData`.

Comment: Is GCD involved here? If so, please provide code for that.

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine the behavior you describe if the `userData` property was defined as `weak` (notably, if `getAllWordsWithBlock` runs asynchronously).

If not, I'd suggest setting up a "watch" on the underlying variable:

- setting a breakpoint at point #1 (and at point #2, presumably) in your code and start the app in the debugger;
- when the debugger stops at your first breakpoint, add a watch on the variable that backs your `userData` property by right-clicking (or <kbd>control</kbd>-clicking) on the variable in the "Variables" view and choosing "Watch" (obviously, this screen snapshot is a different piece of code, but it illustrates how to create a "watch" in Xcode):

  [image: add watch]
- resuming execution by hitting the continue button: [image]
- when you hit a watch breakpoint, sometimes you'll be staring at assembler, but you can hit the "step out" button [image] until you get to a point in your code you recognize.

That can be helpful in identifying what is changing your variable (if not a simple `weak` property problem).